# Disable editing in kendo grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I am trying make the an editable grid to uneditable depend on conditions.

I have tried in jquery as below

```
var $grid = &("#gridName").data("kendogrid");
Var model = $grid.datasource.at(1);
if(model)
  model.field["cell"].editable = false;
```

but here the 'model' is getting undefined.

also tried $grid.data() and then looping through the grid, but the cells are not getting uneditable they are still editable.

Can anyone please let me know how can I make this work.

Comment: Are trying to enable/disable editing the entire table or some field only?

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Issue is resolved.

```
var $grid = &("#gridName").data("kendoGrid");
var len= &("#gridName").data("kendoGrid tbody tr").length();
for(i=0;i<=len ; i++)
{
var model = $grid.datasource.at(i);
if(model)
  model.fields["cell"].editable = false;
}
```

Comment: Your original question was "Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong." and I told you. Again you also have syntax errors. Did you really tried your code? Can you put it JSFiddle and show it running? If you want to see how to convert a column to do not editable, please check my **EDIT** in the previous answer.

Answer (score 15):

You have some typographic errors...

Try this instead:

```
var $grid = $("#gridName").data("kendoGrid");
var model = $grid.dataSource.at(1);
if (model)
    model.fields["cell"].editable = false;
```

1. Line 1. In `data` it is *kendoGrid* and not *kendogrid*.
2. Line 2. In `model` it is *var* and not *Var*
3. Line 4. It is `fields` and not `field`

**EDIT:** If you want to change `"cell"` column to not editable, simply do:

```
var $grid = $("#gridName").data("kendoGrid");
$grid.dataSource.at(0).fields["cell"].editable = false;
```

You just need to change it to one row since the model is shared by all rows in the grid.

See it running in JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/GuyPa/

Comment: Modified the lines, still having the issue.

Comment: @OnaBai Hey man, what if i just want to change say the editable value and validation.min on a specific column in a specific row? say the min value for some column in row 1 is 3 and in row 2 for same column min is 1 or something...

Comment: @OnaBai seems if I do   $grid.dataSource.at(idx).fields.MyField.validation.min = SomeDynamicMinValue; then that someDynamicMinValue gets set for the entire column anyway, not just the one row... hmmmmmm not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: Right, fields refer to the `model` i.e. the definition of the column.

Comment: so, we can't make cell of a specific row non editable or is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Jain, you can do it programmatically. When you detect an edition event you check the condition and cancel the edition if you don't want it to be editable.

Comment: I did it, but when I made a cell non editable, that cell becomes non editable in all other rows as well, which is not what I desire.

Comment: @jain you should do the cell editable an close it when not desired.

Answer (score 2):

to disable cell editing:

```
 var len = $("#gridName").find("tbody tr").length;
    for(var i=0;i<=len ; i++)
    {
        var model = $("#gridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.at(i);
        if (model) {//field names
            model.fields["DueDateStr"].editable = false;
            model.fields["TotalAmount"].editable = false;
            model.fields["IsPercentage"].editable = false;
        }

    }
```

to disabled check box control's which it in the template:

```
$.map($("#gridName").find("input:checkbox"),
        function (item) {
            $(item).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    );
```

to remove command buttons like delete button:

```
 var rows = $('#gridName tbody tr');
    $.map(rows, function (row) {
        //cell buttons index
        row.cells[4].innerHTML = "";

    });
```

to hide toolbar grid:

```
$("#gridName .k-grid-toolbar").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using "incell" edit mode, the grid has an "edit" event you could use to immediately close the cell.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({

  ...

  edit: function(e) {
      if ( ... ) {
          this.closeCell();
      }
  }

  ...

});
```

A more powerful approach would be to subclass the kendoGrid and override the editCell and/or editRow methods.  Then you can do whatever you want.  [Look here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/howto/create-custom-kendo-widget) for info on subclassing kendo widgets.

Comment: This works but if you have an editor such as a dropdown, you might notice a flash as it opens it then closes it. 

Instead you could use the `beforeEdit` event and `e.preventDefault()` so the cell doesn't open in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```js
for(i=0;i<=$("#grid").find("tbody tr").length ; i++)
{ 
  var model = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.at(i);
  if(model)
  {
      model.fields[$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").columns[i].field].editable = false;    
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/parthiv89/qwtyLmhk/

I hope this works well..if works then don't forget to vote me..