# How disable editing in all columns but one in a Kendo Grid?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I know how to disable a grid entirely by using

```
$(controlId + ' .k-grid-content table').css('pointer-events', 'none');
```

but the problem is that I need some columns to remain enabled because some columns will contain a popup that a user may want to view and if I use the above code then I can't access the columns that have popups.

My grid has about 15 columns and one column has a popup

Any idea's or direction on this?

Comment: Use classes or data attributes to identify which columns should be enabled or disabled?

Comment: @input, placing the grid into a readonly mode with allowing one column to not in readonly will be based on returned data

Comment: Pretty much a user may be able to only view an order, but not modify any of the data in the grids

Comment: found my answers in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402953/disable-editing-in-kendo-grid

Answer (score 0):

when edit grid I use :

```
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)
```

and when I need edit some column  , I set Editable in Model = true

My Kendo Grid :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GridData>()
    .Name("MyGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
     {
            columns.Bound(p => p.id).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.AAA).Title("a");
            columns.Bound(p => p.BBB).Title("b");
            columns.Bound(p => p.CCC).Title("c");                           
     })              
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
          .Pageable(p => p.Input(false)
           .PageSizes(false))
           .AutoBind(true)
           .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
                 .Model(m =>
                 {
                     m.Id(e => e.id);       
                     m.Field(e => e.AAA).Editable(false);
                     m.Field(e => e.BBB).Editable(true); **// edit this**
                     m.Field(e => e.CCC).Editable(false);
                 })
              .Read(read => read.Action("Action", "Controller")))
              .Events(e => e.DataBound("onGridDataBound"))
 )
```

I hope you will find this information useful.

Comment: I gave the answer a down vote simply because the user is asking a jQuery question and you responded with an MVC answer.